# Doubt in property of order of element of a group.

Tags: group-theory

Given, a group $G,$ if order of an element $g\in G,$ denoted as $o(g)$ has the properties:

1. the least element in the set $\{n\in \mathbb {N} \, : \, g^n =e\};$
2. $\infty,$ if the set in (i) is empty.

[It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHWw.jpg) further states: 
Property 5. $o(g)= h, g^n = e\implies h\mid n.$
The proof given is based on the division algorithm, by using the fact that $h$ is the smallest positive integer $k,$ s.t. $g^k = e.$

The proof is as follows:
Writing $n = qh + r, 0\le r\lt$ have $e = g^n = g^{qh+r}= (g^h)^q\cdot g^r = e^q\cdot g^r= g^r.$
Since, by definition $h$ is the least integer $k,$ s.t. $g^k = e,\, r\lt h$ is necessarily zero. But, that is to say $h\mid n.$

Doubt: Why it is not stated that $h= n?$ It is not that $o(G)=n,$ and both $h, n$ are specified as the order of $g$ only.

Say, if have $C_6=\{e,1,2,3,4,5\},$ with $o(\langle 2\rangle)= 3, o(\langle 5\rangle)= 6.$

So, does by $o(g),$ the property refers to set of all possible orders, if elements in the group $G.$
But, then the identity element $e$ must be eliminated from the above.

Also in $C_6,$ have $o(\langle 3\rangle)=2, o(\langle 2\rangle)= 3.$ So, how $o(\langle 3\rangle)\mid o(\langle 2\rangle)?$ Or, how $o(\langle 2\rangle)\mid o(\langle 3\rangle)?$

*For the purpose of reference, the source is here: [1,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHWw.jpg) [2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt74f.jpg)*

---

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140184/discussion-on-question-by-jiten-doubt-in-property-of-order-of-element-of-a-group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $n$ is a *variable*, whereas $h$ is the least value $n$ can be.

Comment: But, where is this cited? Only have (i), as also stated in the OP,  to state about $n.$

Comment: It's basic set theory, @jiten.

Comment: So, the set in (i) indicates this. But, seems nowhere else such set notation, hence a multiple of values for $n$ is used.

Comment: $n$ is *free* in the sentence in question (it is not bounded by a quantifier). That means there is an implicit "for all $n$". The statement says: "for all $n$, if the order of $g$ is $h$ and $g^n=e$, then $h\mid n$." Because that is how basic math is parsed.

Comment: Is it possible to show a statement of variant that takes $n$ not as a variable, hence fitting my reasoning. Though, then would not fit the book.